# reset inline-css that has been set (only) by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have (please don't fight the reason) the following html

```
<div class="something" style="background: green;"></div>
```

and now need to add `position: fixed` via jQuery

```
$(".something").css("position", "fixed");
```

which leaves me with the following markup in the inspector

```
<div class="something" style="background: green; position: fixed"></div>
```

And noooow I want to erase `; position: fixed` from the `style`-attribute again.

The only solution I came up with is storing the initial `position`-value via `.data()` and then on reversing setting it again.

But that leaves me with the following markup..

```
<div class="something" style="background: green; position: static"></div>
```

Unfortunately I can't have the `position`-property in the `style`-attribute afterwards. It overwrites my css coming on some class changes etc.

## what I want:

I am now looking for a way to delete the parts of the `style`-attribute that jQuery has put there... something like `$(".something").css("position", unset);`

## Please NO `!important` suggestions for my css!

## I am more looking for a clean way to solve this issue in general, rather than a solution for my specific problem here

Comment: Find out what position it should have with your class changes and change it to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove a specific CSS style property, you can use the [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function and set it to an empty string to remove it :

```
// This will set the position attribute back to its original value
$('.something').css('position','');
```

Comment: I swear to you I tried that; and it didn't work for me– but now it does!
Well now there atleast is proof in the web. I couldn't find s#!t about it on the webs. Any suggestions for a better title then? 
[EDIT again] Stack just told me this question has already been answered– I question my google skillz :X